# Synonym [eva] and [spacewalk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[space-walk] is [already a synonym](https://space.stackexchange.com/tags/eva/synonyms) but [spacewalk](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacewalk) has 32 questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completed the merge and synonym!